# Observation of a point charge in an accelerated frame of reference

Tags: electromagnetism, reference-frames

Let us us consider a test charge q which is a point charge. It is currently at rest wrt an inertial frame of reference. Say we now rigidly attach a coordinate system to an accelerated frame of reference. According to this frame the charge would be moving with an acceleration caused by a pseudo force due to the accelerating reference frame. A magnetic field is formed when a charged particle accelerates. Is a magnetic field formed in this case. If so with which frame is this observed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see how things look in different frames is to use tensors. In an inertial frame the EM field tensor is $$F^{\mu \nu }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -E_x & -E_y & -E_z \\
 E_x & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
 E_y & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
 E_z & -B_y & B_x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

So for a point charge located at $(x,y,z)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ the EM field tensor is $$ F^{\mu \nu }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{k q
   \left(x_0-x\right)}{\left(\left(x-x_0\right){}^2+\left(y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & \frac{k q
   \left(y_0-y\right)}{\left(\left(x-x_0\right){}^2+\left(y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & \frac{k q
   \left(z_0-z\right)}{\left(\left(x-x_0\right){}^2+\left(y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} \\
 \frac{k q
   \left(x-x_0\right)}{\left(\left(x-x_0\right){}^2+\left(y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 & 0
   \\
 \frac{k q
   \left(y-y_0\right)}{\left(\left(x-x_0\right){}^2+\left(y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 & 0
   \\
 \frac{k q
   \left(z-z_0\right)}{\left(\left(x-x_0\right){}^2+\left(y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 & 0
   \\
\end{array}
\right) $$ where the 0's in the off-diagonal elements of the bottom-right 3x3 matrix indicate that there is no B field in the inertial frame.

We then transform to the Rindler frame to obtain $$ F^{\mu \nu }=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{k q \left(x_0-X \cosh (g T)\right)}{g X
   \left(\left(x_0-X \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & \frac{k q \cosh (g T) \left(y_0-Y\right)}{g
   X \left(\left(x_0-X \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & \frac{k q \cosh (g T) \left(z_0-Z\right)}{g
   X \left(\left(x_0-X \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} \\
 \frac{k q \left(X \cosh (g T)-x_0\right)}{g X \left(\left(x_0-X
   \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & 0 & \frac{k q \sinh (g T)
   \left(Y-y_0\right)}{\left(\left(x_0-X \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & \frac{k q \sinh (g T)
   \left(Z-z_0\right)}{\left(\left(x_0-X \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} \\
 \frac{k q \cosh (g T) \left(Y-y_0\right)}{g X \left(\left(x_0-X
   \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & \frac{k q \sinh (g T)
   \left(y_0-Y\right)}{\left(\left(x_0-X \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{k q \cosh (g T) \left(Z-z_0\right)}{g X \left(\left(x_0-X
   \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & \frac{k q \sinh (g T)
   \left(z_0-Z\right)}{\left(\left(x_0-X \cosh (g
   T)\right){}^2+\left(Y-y_0\right){}^2+\left(Z-z_0\right){}^2\right){}^{3/2}} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$ where the capital letters indicate coordinates in the accelerating frame and $g$ is the acceleration of the Rindler frame. The presence of the off-diagonal terms in the lower right 3x3 matrix indicates that there is a B field in the accelerating frame.

Comment: "to see how things look in different frames is to use tensors."  BUT, this is an accelerating frame.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin Yes. That is why I used the Rindler transform instead of the Lorentz transform. The $g$ is the acceleration

Comment: @Dale According to you answer magnetic field is frame dependent? Because it exists in one frame and doesn’t exist in the other frame. Please forgive me as I am still in 12th so I quite don’t understand the tensors part.

Comment: @TheCuriousOne yes, the magnetic field is frame dependent. That is well established in the scientific literature, and applies even for inertial frames, not just accelerating frames. If $E^2-B^2$ is positive then there is an inertial frame where $B=0$ and if it is negative then there is an inertial frame where $E=0$